# how to center vertically and horizontaly an image on a floated div without knowing image widths or heights?

Tags: css, centering

Good browsers out of equation, it needs to be valid on IE 8 and sup;
How to center image on a floated div without knowing image width or height ?

The image is semantically relevant so, it cannot be a background;
The html:

```
<div class="logo-organization-home">
 <img src="images/logoOrganization1.png" alt="logo organization 1"/>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.logo-organization-home {
    float:left;
    background-color: #fafaed;
    border: 4px solid #f7f4ee;
    width: 18%;
}
```

I've tried display:table-cell; no success;
I've tried text-align center with a certain padding: no success;

Failed try:
http://cssdesk.com/pQnRG

Thanks

Comment: Any proper solution regarding the code here stated ?

Answer (score 0):

To center horizontaly, use: 'text-align:center' for .logo-organization-home

Answer (score 0):

If the containing element has a width, you can use the following:

```
.logo-organization-home img {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Concerning horizontal centering, the example that you linked to here: http://cssdesk.com/pQnRG does not work properly since the width of the div is smaller than the width of the image. If you increase the width to 40% for example, you'll see that the image will be centered correctly, even when the containing div has a padding.

Concerning vertical centering, display:table-cell "requires a !DOCTYPE. IE9" on IE8. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp Alternatively, although unethical, you can use a table/row/cell directly as an additional container:

```
.logo-organization-home {
    float:left;
    background-color: #fafaed;
    border: 4px solid #f7f4ee;
    width: 18%;
}
table{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
td{
    vertical-align:center;
    text-align:center;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="logo-organization-home">
    <table><tr><td>
        <img src="images/logoOrganization1.png" alt="logo organization 1"/>
    </td></tr></table>
</div>
```